# How to keep track of divs being clicked and pass the id to a string in the codebehind?

Tags: jquery

I am going to have a dynamically created table, with divs in every cell. The divs are built off of database values, I.E the divs id will be an id from the database, the innertext will be subject from the database. I'm going to use JQuery to listen for the divs being clicked.
What I need to do is that when every time a div button gets clicked, I need to put the divs id to a string and append the string with any other div that is clicked. So then I can send the string to the database of the ids.
I know that JavaScript can interact with strings in the codebehind page, so I'm assuming that JQuery can do the same.

I have no code to provide at the moment, I'm just working out everything in my head and starting the dynamic tables and divs. But hopefully my explanation and question were clear enough.

I know I'm doing this to get each time a div gets clicked, its on the click event that I don't know what to do with.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("div").click(function () {
        });
    });
</script>
```

I don't know much about JQuery, just bits and pieces, so forgive me if this is something easy to accomplish.

Comment: You'll need to have a better understanding of what you want to do. Developing is more than working things out in your head. You'll need to try things out, and find out what you can get to work and what you can't get to work. Look up the documentation of `$.ajax(...)`. Other than that the subject is waaaay too broad to provide an answer I fear.

Comment: @Sumurai8, I had a better understanding on what I wanted to do. Sometimes I find it hard to explain what I am trying to do. But I was lucky enough that the two that answered understood. So, I was working on a bootstrap page and was working it out in my head on what I wanted to accomplish, because bootstraps css was making my checkboxlist all muddled and I was having issues on overriding the css. So I was looking for a way to use JQuery and treat my divs like checkboxs. I am going to look at what you suggested with Ajax, I have come across it before while searching around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example - http://jsfiddle.net/Fq9M5/

```
 $('div').click(function() {
        var divID = this.id;
    });
```

Comment: That example was perfect, thank you so much. I'll accept as answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

This will apply the click event to each div, you will need a variable outside the scope of the method that will hold your list of ids, each time the user clicks on the div, it will add the id to the array of ids:

[example:](http://jsfiddle.net/UYy7W/)

```
var idList = [];
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div').each(function () {
        $(this).on('click', function () {
            idList.push(this.id);
            alert(idList);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks because this just answered my next question :)

Comment: @user2970223 sure, no problem, reading into your question this was at least what it sounded like you were going to try be doing. Hope it helps.

Comment: It does help out a lot. Because at some point I would have had to figure out how to do this with a list. The one question that it does bring up is, the idList, can I access that list in my codebehind page with c#?